# WP8 call method in viewmodel from object in collection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I have a longlistselector and in each row I have ToggleSwitch and I would like to call http request via my ApiService when ToggleSwitch is changed. I have ApiService class in ViewModel thanks to injection and in ViewModel I have ObservableCollection of Modules which have switches. I bind it with datatemplate and there is no problem with bind ToggleSwitch to bool property. But what should I do in setter of that property?

Model - Modul.cs

```
public int IsLock
    {
        get { return isLock; }
        set { 
            Set(() => IsLock, ref isLock, value); 
            // What should I do here? How call ViewModel method?
        }
    }
```

ViewModel - ModuleListViewModel.cs

```
 public ObservableCollection<Module> Modules { get; private set; }

 // here I have apiService instance
 // and here I could call apiService.Lock(module) and so on
```

View - part of DataTemplate

```
 <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsLock, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

What's the right aproach for this? Maybe I could have ApiService class in each Modul class but I think that's very bad. I think ViewModel should somehow findout that Model was changed and it should call method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the ToggleSwitch's `Command` property -- that will get executed every time the user changes the toggle, and will allow you to bind to the parent data context.  Use something like this in the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch"
                Command="{Binding ElementName=items,Path=DataContext.LockToggleCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsLock, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then just add the "LockToggleCommand" to your main view model, and call the service, eg:

```
public ObservableCollection<Module> Modules { get; private set; }

public ICommand LockToggleCommand { get; private set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    LockToggleCommand = new DelegateCommand<Module>(module => {
        apiService.Lock(module);
    });
}
```

Here "DelegateCommand" is just the usual implementation of `ICommand` -- I am sure that MVVM Light has its own standard implementation.

---

**Edit**

I thought that `ToggleSwitch` supported `Command`, but since it doesn't, you can take a similar approach using an EventTrigger (if you are willing to add the System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions DLLs to your project):

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsLock, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Toggled">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=items,Path=DataContext}"
                                             MethodName="OnToggled"
                                             />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now add the "OnToggled" method to the main view model -- use the "sender" parameter to get the current item, something like this:

```
public void OnToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var toggleSwitch = (ToggleSwitch)sender;
    var module = (Module)toggleSwitch.DataContext;
    apiService.Lock(module);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using Command property (and CommandParameter) like with Button but ToggleSwitch doesn't have these properties.

Comment: @LiborZapletal my mistake -- I'm surprised it doesn't support Command.  I added a different approach to my answer.